# Scala - Keep Map in foreach

Tags: scala, dictionary

```
    var myMap:Map[String, Int] = Map()
    myRDD.foreach { data =>
        println( "1. " + data.name + " : " + data.time)
        myMap += ( data.name -> data.time)
        println( "2. " + myMap)
    }
    println( "Total Map : " + myMap)
```

Result

> 1. A : 1
> 2. Map(A -> 1)
> 3. B: 2
> 4. Map(B -> 2) // deleted key A
> 5. C: 3
> 6. Map(C -> 3) // deleted Key A and B
>
> Total Map : Map() // nothing

Somehow I cannot store Map data in foreach. It kept deleting or initialing previous data when adding new key&value.
Any Idea of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark closures are serialized and executed in a separate context (remotely when in a cluster). `myMap` variable will not be updated locally.

To get the data from the RDD as a map, there's a built-in operation:

```
val myMap = rdd.collectAsMap()
```

Comment: Data has class and there are many fields in it. How to set map's key and value with specific field of class.

Comment: Solved! Translate origin rdd as new rdd ( key, value) type and do collectAsMap(). Thanks :)